# Error adding schema to XmlSchemaSet

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I am trying to add an xsd into an XmlSchemaSet but get the following error "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

```
 XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schemas.Add("", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(@"C:\source\Net4\Clocks\Handlers\XML_Schemas\test.xsd")));

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="interface">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="node1" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="node2" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="node3" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="node4" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="node5" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
              <xs:element name="node6">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="node6" type="xs:dateTime" />
                    <xs:element name="node7" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass contents of a file into `StringReader`, not the path to a file.

```
var pathToFile = @"C:\source\Net4\Clocks\Handlers\XML_Schemas\test.xsd";

var reader = new StringReader(File.ReadAllText(pathToFile));

schemas.Add("", XmlReader.Create(reader));
```

Alternativ way to add reader to `XmlSchemaSet` is

```
schemas.Add("", new XmlTextReader(pathToFile));
```